# Attachment link in excel that connected from the Purchase requisition in D365

Tags: excel, connector, erp

i am trying to built a report where i can export the Purchase requisition lines from D365. In the D365 we can retrieve the attachment from the transaction itself. However, I am to include the link that embedded in Microsoft excel and able to retrieve from the link.

Looking forward to your answer.

thanks

Best Regard
James

able to embeded the link where it can be downloaded the attachment when clicked on the link